# Adeles of Holomorphic Functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

In number theory, an adele is a restricted product of elements of the completion at each prime. For function fields, we take (a kind of) product of the completion at each point, and at non-singular points, this completion is a ring of formal power series. The adeles are intuitively defined so that we have an injective homomorphism from the ring of functions on a given open set (Zariski open for a number field) to the adeles for that open set.

My question is, what if we replace formal power series by *convergent* Laurent series (i.e. in the complex topology)? This is what I might call a holomorphic adele. There is a natural injective map from the ring of meromorphic functions on an open set to the ring of adeles on that set. We can also put a topology on these "holomorphic adeles" similar to how it's normally done. Is this construction ever considered? Might it be useful? Is there a connection between the adelic topology and the complex topology?

Comment: There is a notion of "Parabolic bundle" in algebraic geometry, considered by Seshadri and others. You might find that relevant.

Comment: I don't know if they're *really* useful, but if I recall correctly the proof of Serre duality in Fulton's algebraic topology book uses them.